# How to set the selected item background color in ListView (.Net MAUI) for UWP

Tags: maui

I need to highlight the selected item color. We need solution for Windows platform(UWP)

i found ans
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QWe6.png)

Comment: Do not post code as image.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use the `Selected` VisualState that can be used to initiate a visual change to the selected item in the CollectionView. You can check this link about [Change selected item color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/selection?view=net-maui-7.0#change-selected-item-color).

Second, You can change the color.xml file for each platform.

For android, change the style.xml on the android platform.

```
<resources>
   <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
       <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
       <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
       <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
       <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
  </style>
    <color name="ListViewSelected">#FFFFFFFF</color>
    <color name="ListViewHighlighted">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

For windows, you can add the code to the App.xaml in the windows platform.

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
  <StaticResource x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
    <StaticResource x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush"  Color="Red" />

</maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
```

Comment: I tried for  window's it is not working

Comment: Sorry, It's my mistake. I have changed the code and now it works well. You can check the code for windows platform.

Comment: Working fine but on "PointerOver" to the same selected item it is changing back to default gray color

Comment: Ad this to App.Xml in the windows folder

Comment: You can see the source code [ListViewItem_themeresources.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/cb181acede22577c59c5dc250361d3340252f4e9/dev/CommonStyles/ListViewItem_themeresources.xaml) for more styles.

Comment: @sowndarrajanvijayaragavan It works well now. I changed the code to remove the pointover color effect.